# Relative reactivities of alkyl halides in an E2 reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides

What is the exact order of reactivity of alkyl halides in an E2 reaction?

Organic Chemistry by Paula Yurikanis Bruice says that the order is $3^\circ>2^\circ>1^\circ$. And I think this order is correct because the transition state of the tertiary alkyl halide will be better stabilized by more hyperconjugating structures as compared to the secondary and primary halides.

But my teacher made me write that the order is $3^\circ<2^\circ<1^\circ$ and I even saw the this order in a book.

So I'm kind of confused about the correct order in E2  mechanism.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you might be mixing up E1 and E2 elimination reactions. In the first case the reaction first proceeds by formation of a carbocation from the alkyl halide and then a proton extractio. In this case, the order of reactivity is indeed $3^∘>2^∘>1^∘$ as such is the order of carbocation stability - in order the E1 reaction to proceed the carbocation must be formed.

But the situation is completely different in an E2 elimination. In this case the mechanism is the abstraction of the proton that is oriented *anti* to the halide with the simultaneous formation of the double bond and halide leaving the molecule as anion. That means that in this case the stability of carbocation plays no role and the significant factor are the sterical considerations. If the carbon atoms around the halide make it hard for the base to get to the *anti* proton then the reaction is less likely to proceed *via* E2 mechanism.

But bear in mind that usually both E1 and E2 elimination can take place and because of that tertiary halides would usually undergo elimination more readily than primary halides - just not *via* E2 mechanism.

More details on the E2 mechanism, with pictures: [Master Organic Chemistry](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2012/09/27/the-e2-mechanism/)

Comment: Nobody is talking about carbocation. We are talking about transition state.

Comment: @Jan Rzymkowski I am aware of E1, E2 & E1cb and i'm really not mixing them up. According to you, the order should be $3^\circ<2^\circ<1^\circ$ right? but what about the stable transition state that can be attained when a tertiary halide undergoes elimination?

Comment: If you have a stable transition state with a carbocation then you have an E1 reaction, not E2 reaction. As I said, tertiary halide is generally more reactive than primary, because of that possible carbocation - but it's not more reactive in **E2** mechanism.

Comment: Here you have a transition state for E2 mechanism: http://iverson.cm.utexas.edu/courses/310M/ReactMoviesFl05%20/E2scheme.gif
If your transition state is a carbocation, then the reaction proceeds via E1 mechanism, not E2 mechanism.

Comment: Not a transition state with a carbocation. In fact a carbocation cannot be called a transition state. It is a reaction intermediate, and please stop talking about E1 here. We are not confused about what is E1 and what is E2.  For your reference here is one pdf: http://home.iitk.ac.in/~madhavr/CHM102/Lec13.pdf. Check page 6. Here is another: http://ocw.uci.edu/upload/files/51b_chapter8_f2014.pdf. Maybe the problem is that we have different understanding of the word "reactivity".

Comment: Perhaps it would be more helpful to think of the transition state as alkene-like instead; also stabilised by hyperconjugation, but not a carbocation

Answer (score 1):

In E1 and E2 both are same reactivity order of alkyl halide because both of reaction 3^• alkyl halide give easily product because after elimination reaction on 3^•alkyle halide. alkene is attached more alpha hydrogen which is more stable.so reactivity order in E1and E2 both are same 3^•>2^•>1^and is also same  in SN1 and but different in SN2